# django date output format with 2 digits with leading zeros

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the `date=timezone.now().date()` with this output:
`datetime.date(2016, 2, 25)`, but I prefer that the output has 2 digits like `datetime.date(2016, 02, 25)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strftime` method:

```
from django.utils import timezone

date = timezone.now().date()
print date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
# Prints '2016/02/25'
```

You can check out this [unofficial strftime reference](http://strftime.org/) for more details, or the [official docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: I do not want a string but I want the class datetime.date

Comment: Your question is regarding output. That means rendering a string. When you output the datetime, you are rendering the datetime as a string and then outputting it. Without subclassing the datetime object, or monkeypatching its `str`/`unicode` functions, this is the way to do what you want (and honestly, it's preferable to doing either of those other things).